# Alternative initial value for entity in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity and their mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", initialValue = 20000)
```

I want id value begins in 20000 but it doesn't work in postgresql. When the application starts I receive this exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to
>   database sequence [sequence_generator] were encountered attempting to
>   set conflicting values for 'initial value'.  Fou nd [20000] and [1]

Do I need a extra configuration to it works?

**PS:** It is a new database without any previous configuration

Comment: It seems you defined two `@SequenceGenerator`s with the same name

Answer (score 1):

You could try @TableGenerator annotation. Initial values can be set and seed other values. 
You can find example and documentation here:
[Set Initial Value Of Table Generator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetInitialValueOfTableGenerator.htm)